# Using Kendo UI AutoComplete to throw error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-ui

hi i am using kedo ui for my asp.net mvc project i am able to use autocomplete and i am getting products from the database which is working fine but i dont want to select the existing products what should i do if already product is entered into the textbox the it should throw an error

```
    <%= Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
      .Name("produciits")
      .DataTextField("ProductName")
      .Filter("contains")
      .DataSource(source => {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetProducts", "Home");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(false);
      })
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem correctly, you want to avoid duplicate items within autocomplete textbox using some separator. If it be the case, you have to wire up some manual work in onChange event of autocomplete as of following snippet, if not please clarify a bit.

```
<%= Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
      .Name("produciits")
      .Separator(",")
      .DataTextField("ProductName")
      .Filter("contains")
      .DataSource(source => {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetProducts", "Home");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(false);
      })
.Events(e => e.Select("onChange"))
%>

<script>
    function onChange(e) {
        var text = e.item.text(),
            valArray = this.value().split(",");
        if ($.inArray(text, valArray) !== -1) {

            alert(text + " already selected");
            // Retaining previous values
            e.preventDefault();            
            valArray.pop();
            this.value(valArray.join(",") + ",");
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you just want to stick with datasource items, i would recommend you to use [multiselect](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/multiselect/index.html) which automatically keeps track of what is already selected.